# Return Connected Node's Properties Instead of RID using OUT() in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, sqlplus, graph-databases

I am attempting to store a connected Node's data in a property of a selected Node in OrientDB via the OUT() projection. e.g.:

```
SELECT *, OUT("Has_Friend") AS Friends FROM Person
```

Given that a "Person" Node is connected to several "Friend" Nodes via the "Has_Friend" Edge, I would like the actual Friend Node properties to be stored in the "Friends" property on each Person Node returned by this query. e.g.:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Friends": [
                {
                 "Name": "Ben",
                 "Title": "Mr."
                },
                {
                 "Name": "Stan",
                 "Title": "Dr."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Tim",
            "Friends": [
                {
                 "Name": "Terrance",
                 "Title": "Esq."
                },
                {
                 "Name": "Sarah",
                 "Title": "Dr."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the query only stores the RID of each "Friend" Node in the "Friends" property rather than the actual data of that "Friend" Node. e.g.:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Friends": [
                "#228:1",
                "#227:1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Tim",
            "Friends": [
                "#225:1",
                "#226:1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've searched the OrientDB documentation but am unsure as to how I might accomplish this. I suspect there's a way to nest queries for those Friend nodes inside of the primary query, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try to use [expand()](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Functions.html#expand) function. It would expands the document pointed by that link and give all properties of this document. So your query should looks like this one:

```
SELECT expand(in("Has_Friend")) AS Friend FROM Person
```